# Keras output layer for multiclass classification problem with value range -128 to 127

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have an input layer of 128 neurons. Two hidden layers of 128 neurons each with relu activation function. Now I am having difficulty constructing my output layer. You can compare the input value with the pixel value of mnist dataset. Each input (128 numeric value) has an output from the range of -128 to 127. Each value from this range (-128 to 127) represents an output class. I have contracted an output layer of 256 with the activation function sigmoid.

My code is

```
model_1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(128,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(128,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(128,), activation='sigmoid')
])

model_1.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5)
```

In my training data set, the input and output are int8 data type. But I get an error like this

`"INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received a label value of -124 which is outside the valid range of [0, 255).  Label values: 44 -26 -120 -73 -84 -21 -123 90 -14 76 -43 -8 72 -94 -78 60 -121 -98 -124 106 -79 72 -2 -79 -116 55 0 6 82 -45 -35 -17"`

Can anyone please help me with this? Is the problem in my loss function? How can I tell the output layer that I have outputs class from a range of -128 to 127?

Answer (score 0):

**note a-side** : from the loss function it's clear that the model meant to be a classifier , the output layer has 255 neuron that's too many .

the number of neurons in output layer must be the same as the labels
in (some cases) the range of of the array (y)

so when you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` you should convert **class vectors to binary class matrices**

[to category](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/to_categorical.html)

Comment: In the output layer, 256 neurons are needed because I have 256 classes for this particular problem. But I have found the problem.  The problem was with my data set. But thank you for your comment.